# Debugger in python for Google App Engine and Django

Tags: django, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am having a problem that has baffled me for over a week.   I have a project that is written in python with Django on Google App Engine.   The project has a login page and when I run the application in Google App Engine or from the command line using dev_server.py c:\project, it works fine.  When I try to run the application through a debugger like Wing or Pycharm, I cannot get past the login page.  After trying to login, it takes me back to the login screen again.   When I look at the logs, it shows a 302 (redirect) in the debugger but normally it shows a 200 (OK).   Could someone explain why this would be happening?

Thanks
-Dimitry

Comment: This is not an answer, but more of a question that might be helpful. When I tried debugging GAE application with `ipdb` it didn't work, whereas with `pdb` it did. May have to do with the kind of debugger your IDE is using?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a great answer since I don't know much about Wing or Pycharm.  But dev_appserver reroutes stdin and stdout to the WSGI handler.  If you hit a breakpoint set by pdb.set_trace(), the breakpoint usually drops you to a shell that uses stdin/stdout, but with dev_appserver, you'll see the debugger shell piped to your HTTP, and there's no input available.

I'm not sure how Wing/Pycharm handle this.  Pydev with eclipse works with dev_appserver, but that might be because of the GAE eclipse plugin.

I find myself often embedding breakpoints in my code and debugging manually at the shell, mostly because it runs way faster than in the pydev debugger.  I do this be rerouting stdin/stdout back to the terminal when I hit a breakpoint.  http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/12076034867/using-pdb-on-app-engine

I'm on a linux environment.  I did work with the GAE app launcher on Windows for a little bit, but not recently.  I think I recall the app launcher hiding the original terminal that launches dev_appserver, so you might have to launch dev_appserver from the command prompt for this to work.  I suspect you may need similar hacks if Wing or Pycharm use pdb underneath.

Comment: I found that get_current_session is blank through the debugger.  Not sure why.  When running out of the debugger, it is fine.   This is a windows 64 bit machine.

Comment: Are you using the Google User API?  That API works on dev_appserver by setting environment variables that contained the logged in user.  If your debugger does anything with os.environ, it might screw up what the Users API is doing.

Answer (score 1):

After a week of racking my brain, I finally figured out the problem.   The gaesessions code was the culprit.   We put DEFAULT_LIFETIME = datetime.timedelta(hours=1) and originally it was DEFAULT_LIFETIME = datetime.timedelta(days=7).   Not sure why running it through any debugger such as wing or pycharm would prevent the browser from getting a session.   The interesting thing is the code change with hours=1 works fine on linux with wing debugger.  Very Strange!

Comment: After talking to the Wing IDE developer, he said Windows users will probably want to set the TZ environment variable to UTC via the environment field in Project Properties to work around problems with setting os.environ['TZ'] while a process is running (see Issues on Microsoft Windows for details about the Windows runtime bug)...here is the link for runtime bug (http://wingware.com/doc/install/trouble-win32)

Thanks
-Dimitry